# Best practice for integrating CherryPy web-framework, SQLAlchemy sessions and lighttpd to serve a high-load webservice

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, lighttpd, cherrypy

I'm developing a CherryPy FastCGI server behind lighttpd with the following setup to enable using ORM SQLAlchemy sessions inside CherryPy controllers. However, when I run stress tests with 14 concurrent requests for about 500 loops, it starts to give errors like `AttributeError: '_ThreadData' object has no attribute 'scoped_session_class'` in `open_dbsession()` or `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'scoped_session_class'` in `close_dbsession()` after a while. The error rate is around 50% in total.

This happens only when I run the server behind lighttpd, not when it's run directly through `cherrypy.engine.start()`. It's confirmed that `connect()` isn't raising exceptions.

I also tried assigning the return value of `scoped_session` to `GlobalSession` (like it does [here](http://code.google.com/p/webpyte/source/browse/trunk/webpyte/sqlalchemy_tool.py)), but then it gave out errors like `UnboundExceptionError` and other SA-level errors. (Concurrency: 10, loops: 1000, error rate: 16%. Occurs even when run directly.)

There are some possible causes but I lack sufficient knowledge to pick one.
1. Are `start_thread` subscriptions unreliable under FastCGI environment? It seems that `open_dbsession()` is called before `connect()`
2. Does `cherrypy.thread_data` get cleared for some reason?

#### server code

```
import sqlalchemy as sa  
from sqlalchemy.orm import session_maker, scoped_session

engine = sa.create_engine(dburi, strategy="threadlocal")  
GlobalSession = session_maker(bind=engine, transactional=False)

def connect(thread_index):  
    cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class = scoped_session(GlobalSession)

def open_dbsession():  
    cherrypy.request.scoped_session_class = cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class

def close_dbsession():  
    cherrypy.request.scoped_session_class.remove()


cherrypy.tools.dbsession_open = cherrypy.Tool('on_start_resource', open_dbsession)  
cherrypy.tools.dbsession_close = cherrypy.Tool('on_end_resource', close_dbsession)  
cherrypy.engine.subscribe('start_thread', connect)
```

#### lighttpd fastcgi config

```
...
var.server_name = "test"
var.server_root = "/path/to/root"
var.svc_env = "test"
fastcgi.server = (
  "/" => (
    "cherry.fcgi" => (
      "bin-path" => server_root + "/fcgi_" + server_name + ".fcgi",
      "bin-environment" => (
        "SVC_ENV" => svc_env
      ),
      "bin-copy-environment" => ("PATH", "LC_CTYPE"),
      "socket" => "/tmp/cherry_" + server_name + "." + svc_env + ".sock",
      "check-local" => "disable",
      "disable-time"    => 1,
      "min-procs"       => 1,
      "max-procs"       => 4,
    ),
  ),
)
```

#### edits

- Restored the missing `thread_index` argument in the code example from the original source code (thanks to the comment)
- Clarified that errors do not occur immediately
- Narrowed down the conditions to lighttpd

Comment: Just in case, you migh be interested in using the code at https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/d140e6da973aa271e6b68a8bc187e53615674c5e/web/database/sql_alchemy/ It probably better fits the CherryPy workflow and datamodel.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `plugins.ThreadManager.acquire_thread`, you'll see the line `self.bus.publish('start_thread', i)`, where `i` is the array index of the seen thread. Any listener subscribed to the `start_thread` channel needs to accept that `i` value as a positional argument. So rewrite your connect function to read: `def connect(i):`

My guess it that's failing silently somehow; I'll see if I can track that down, test and fix it.

Comment: It certainly does *not* fail silently. Check your error logs; they should have caught this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I checked the function and it already had the argument. (I seem to have left it out of the code example. I'm editing it back. Apologies.)

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried assigning the return value of scoped_session to GlobalSession (like it does here), but then it gave out errors like UnboundExceptionError and other SA-level errors. (Concurrency: 10, loops: 1000, error rate: 16%)

This error did not occur if I didn't instantiate the scoped_session class explicitly.

i.e.

```
GlobalSession = scoped_session(session_maker(bind=engine, transactional=False))

def connect(thread_index):  
    cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class = GlobalSession

def open_dbsession():  
    cherrypy.request.scoped_session_class = cherrypy.thread_data.scoped_session_class

def close_dbsession():  
    cherrypy.request.scoped_session_class.remove()
```